# I am not getting proper output toolbar in my android application

Tags: material-design, android-toolbar

Anyone can help me to fix that problem

**That is my app_bar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CCC">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**That is my activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.afri.apps.myapplicationtest.MainActivity">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
     />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the toolbar does not match parent in the output

Comment: i just found out the problem which was making the output like that :

Answer (score 0):

i just found out the problem which was making the output like that. I should remove all these `android:padding` in my relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.afri.apps.myapplicationtest.MainActivity">
```